# PHP function file_get_contets($url); returns raw code or executed code?

Tags: php

It returns entire file contents with PHP tag within domain but it returns only echo'ed or viewable content in Cross Domain. Why so?

Answer (score 2):

`file_get_contents()` is used to get the raw contents of a file. The contents are not parsed nor interpreted; it is a direct read from disk operation.

A URL can be used as a *filename* with this function if the [fopen wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) have been enabled. When called with a url as a parameter, it will return the *rendered result* from the server just as if you typed the URL in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

if you use the url "http://domain/file.php" it will make a HTTP request to the server therefore you get the executed php script.

If you specify the path to the file "/var/www/forlder/file.php" it returns the file content and this is only possible within the filesystem of the local server.

Comment: but in crossdomain you dont have access to /var/www.. and thats the reason why you don't get php from a foreign domain.

Comment: Now i get it :). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

file_get_contents called on cross domain sends Http requests to the url's server and will recieive outputted html from the server almost  like an web browser.But in case of a local request it just outputs contents of file